# How to only allow a command to be ran by the bot owner (me)

Tags: discord.js

Im working on my discord bot and I have a `stop` command. The only problem with it is that it can be ran by anyone. I looked at other posts but didn't understand it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple, just put this in the beginning of the scope where the command is executed:

```
if (message.author.id != "<your id here>") return;
```

Comment: Thanks for the simple answer! It works. I'll mark it correct once stack lets me.

Comment: Also where would I put a message that says "You cannot use this command"

Comment: After the `return`, so `return message.reply('You cannot use this command');`